# Jetbrains Rider - Export Unit Test Results

Tags: unit-testing, testing, export, acceptance-testing, rider

Is there a way to export test results to text / json / xml in [Jetbrains Rider?](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/) From my co-workers, I've heard you can do this in [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) for Visual Studio; since they both are Jetbrains products, I'd assume it's possible in both.

For reference, I'm talking about the "Unit Test" panel (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>)
[image]

Comment: It seems that the export button of Resharper is missing in Rider...? - strange

Comment: @Slesa - fairly certain Rider does not support this as of this time. They may in the near future.